# Why some people using Allah's name for their house, apartments like (Al- noor, Al- kabeer ) is it permissible or a sin?

Tags: blessings-of-allah

Assalamu’alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh my question is i saw some people uses allah's name for their houses like (Al-kabeer,Al noor )If the name has a meaning or refers to a function or quality that only Allah is capable of, like creating, resurrecting, lordship, etc. then it is not permissible to call a human being by these names how can someone use Allah's name for their house,Allah's names all have Alif-Laam at the beginning (eg. Ar-Rahman, Al-'Aleem).
This prefix (alif-lam) makes a very strong form of the name; this prefix is unique to Allah alone
please correct me if im wrong is it a huge sin? may allah guides us to the straight path.

Answer (score 0):

Allah's names are perfect. For example Allah is Kabeer in the perfect sense, meaning Allah is magnificent and grand with perfection while his creation could have the same name but with imperfection. Example a building could be named Kabeer(Magnificent & Grand) but there is always a superior building on some corner of the globe. And the building is bound to have cracks over a period of time and needs constant maintenance. Similarly somebody could have a name Rahman but he can't be a perfect dispenser of mercy towards the creation. He might have shortfalls.

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) said, "Allah has divided mercy into one hundred parts; and
> He retained with Him ninety-nine parts, and sent down to earth one
> part. Through this one part creatures deal with one another with
> compassion, so much so that an animal lifts its hoof over its young
> lest it should hurt it".
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]